# ¿Como implementar un viewpager junto con mi recyclerview?

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-viewpager, slider

*Tengo un recyclerview al cual le quiero implementar un viewpager en un fragment pero al momento de implementarlo e iniciar la aplicacion se crashea y quisiera saber cual es mi problema*

**Mi layout:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bgfooter"
tools:context="com.example.proyect.slider.Fragments.InicioFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
            android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**Mi adapter:**

```
public class AdapterViewPager extends PagerAdapter {
List<Slider> sliderList = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;

public AdapterViewPager(List<Slider> sliderList, Context context) {
    this.sliderList = sliderList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return sliderList.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_image, container, false);
    ImageView imagePager = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagePager);
    Picasso.with(context).load(sliderList.get(position).getImagen()).into(imagePager);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View)object);
}}
```

**Mi Fragment:**

```
public class InicioFragment extends Fragment {
RecyclerView recyclerview;
List<Recycler> listRecycler;
AdapterRecycler adapterRecycler;
ViewPager viewPager;
List<Slider> sliderList;
AdapterViewPager adapterViewPager;
LinearLayout sliderPanel;
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public InicioFragment() {

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPager);
    sliderPanel = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.SliderPanel); 
    recyclerview = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new 
    LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext());
   linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager); 
    pedirImagen
    if (isOnLine()) {
        pedirImagen("http://servidor.mx/app/WebServiceRecycler.php");
        pedirImagen("http://servidor.mx/app/WebServiceSlider.php");//Sera por esta dos url_
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "No se pudo conectar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return view;
}
public void cagarImagen() {
    adapterViewPager = new AdapterViewPager(sliderList, getContext());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
    adapterRecyler = new AdapterRecyler(getContext(), listRecycler);
    recyclerview.setAdapter(adapterRecyler); 
    recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
}

public void pedirImagen(String uri){
    TaskFragment taskFragment = new TaskFragment();
    taskFragment.execute(uri); 

}
private boolean isOnLine() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
            getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo network = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (network != null && network.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
        return  true;

    }else {
        return  false;
    }
}
private class TaskFragment extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String content = Http.getData(params[0]); 
        return content;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String resultado){
        super.onPostExecute(resultado);
        if (resultado == null){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplication(),"No se pudo conectar",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            return;
        }
        sliderList = ParserSlider.parse(resultado);
        listRecycler = ParserRecycler.parse(resultado);
        cagarImagen();
    }
}

public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}}
```

**Error que aparece en el logcat:**

```
06-14 11:52:16.423 24370-24370/com.example.proyect.slider E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.proyect.slider, PID: 24370
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.example.proyect.slider.Adapters.AdapterViewPager.getCount(AdapterViewPager.java:32)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:532)
                                                                                   at com.example.proyect.slider.Fragments.InicioFragment.cagarImagen(InicioFragment.java:71)
                                                                                   at com.example.proyect.slider.Fragments.InicioFragment$TaskFragment.onPostExecute(InicioFragment.java:148)
                                                                                   at com.example.proyect.slider.Fragments.InicioFragment$TaskFragment.onPostExecute(InicioFragment.java:127)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:692)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:709)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Comment: El error es claro. `sliderList` es `null` al pasarselo como parámetro al constructor del `AdapterViewPager`. Revisa que `sliderList = ParserSlider.parse(resultado);` no devuelva `null` el resultado, antes de llamar `cargarImagen()`. De igual forma `listRecycler = ParserRecycler.parse(resultado);` al pasar el parametro en el constructor de `AdapterRecyler`. Si no traen resultados, debe como minimo devolver una lista vacia.

Comment: Revisa lo que comento en mi respuesta @RickV y comenta por favor, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema indicado es:

> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int
>   java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Es debido a que al instanciar el `Adapter` estas enviando una lista con valor null (valor de `sliderList`):

```
 adapterViewPager = new AdapterViewPager(sliderList, getContext());
```

Para resolver este problema, debes asegurar que el `AsyncTask` obtenga una lista de valores, primero revisa `doInBackground()` si el valor de `content` es correcto y tiene el formato adecuado para ser utilizado por `ParserSlider` dentro de `onPostExecute()`

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String content = Http.getData(params[0]); 
    return content;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String resultado){
    super.onPostExecute(resultado);
    ...
    sliderList = ParserSlider.parse(resultado);
    ...

}
```

Comment: Gracias Jorgesys ya solucione ese problema estaba mal la url del webservice ahora que lo solucione no me muestra nada en el viewpager

Comment: ok entonces si todo lo demás funciona y esto en base a la url obtiene los datos :  String content = Http.getData(params[0]);  va a funcionar sin problema.

Comment: Sii todo eso si va bien no me ha generado problema, ahora solo es que no memanda nada en el viewpager

Comment: Revisaste que aquí : adapterViewPager = new AdapterViewPager(sliderList, getContext()); el valor de sliderList tenga elementos? Revisa el LogCat si se muestra algo.